# get random index numbers from a matrix, fortran 90

Tags: function, random, matrix, repeat, fortran90

I am looking for a function or a way to get the index numbers of a 2D matrix:

my example is, I have A(Ly,Lx) where Ly = 100 and Lx = 100

I want to get a random index number of the matrix, such as : Random_node(A) = (random y, random x)

Then I want to do this repeatedly having the constraint that I don't want my random points to be repeated or even not to be close one to each other following a threshold of (let's say) 10 nodes of radius. The matrix is an eulerian 2D matrix (y,x).

Is at least the first question straightforward?

Thank you all!

Albert P

Comment: can't you just use the INDEX function? http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/index/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of getting a random set of locations in your 100x100 matrix.  First, declare a 100x100 matrix of reals:

```
real, dimension(100,100) :: randarray
```

then, put a random number into each element of that array

```
call random_number(randarray)
```

Now, an expression such as

```
randarray > 0.9
```

returns a logical array containing, approximately, 10% true values and 90% false.  By tracking down the locations of the true values you have the random x-es and y-es that you seek.  Indeed you may not need to find those locations at all, you can simply use the expression in masked assignments and similar operations, for example

```
where(randarray>0.9) a = func()
```

as long, of course, as `func` returns a scalar or a 100x100 array.

This approach guarantees that each location is different from all the others.

It does not however, address your constraint that the 'random' locations should not be too close to each other.  That constraint, of course, is a little inconsistent with randomness.

You could, I suppose, break your 100x100 array into 10x10 blocks and choose, randomly, one element in each block.  Would that be a good compromise between your constraints ?

Comment: seems legit Mark, I'll try that!